# Using skewed factor scores from PCA in regression analysis

Tags: regression, pca

I want to use the first predicted factor score from PCA as an independent variable in the regression analysis. The factor score is skewed. Is it plausible to apply the ln transformation to the factor score, so to treat the factor scores as ordinary numeric independent variables?

Comment: What's the problem with it being "skewed"?

Comment: Statistic book recommend to do the transformation of variables in the regression to get better results. The same logic is here. In some cases I get better (significant) results for my models.

Comment: @usεr11852 OP is talking about independent variable not about response.

Comment: Totally misread that! Sorry!